# Regex - Highlight only group 1 and his backreference

Tags: regex

My regex is like:

```
(pattern_that_i_like)(text_to_escape)(\1)
```

I tested and it works, finding what I want. The problem is that with this pattern I highlight all the 3 groups, instead I want to highlight only group 1 and 3. I've tried with positive lookahead for group 2, but it works only without the backreference.

This regex will be used in services like http://regexr.com/ to highlight some errors in a quickly pasted text. So I can't do any second time replacement like using $1 $3.

A simple example could be: `(\w)(o)(\1)` in `wow` to highlight only the 2 w.

There is a way?

Comment: A regex match cannot have *"holes"* in it. But you could use a different service such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) which will highlight the groups with different colors.

Comment: `?:` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a regex match cannot have *"holes"* in it.

But... I've found a workaround for this, using the `\K` construct:

```
(\w+)o+\K(\1)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vA6kH0/1).

`\K` means something like *throw away what you have matched so far*, don't include it in the match.

Since this requires PCRE, it won't work on regxr, but regex101 works fine with this.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the highlighting on http://regexr.com only seems to match the entire matched expression, I don't think this is possible. Whatever regular expression you match will be highlighted in its entirety, not select portions of it.